# jquery :selected not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following snippet of a HTML select box:

```
<select id="Obj_cboscreen" class="menubarselect" name="page">
<option att="1stOption" value="0" selected="">abc</option>
<option att="2ndOption" value="1">def</option>
```

When I run the following pieces of code:

```
var attribute = $('#Obj_cboscreen :selected').attr('att');
var name = $('#Obj_cboscreen :selected').html();
```

I get 1stOption and abc (respectively).

When I change the select box to a different option, for example:

```
<select id="Obj_cboscreen" class="menubarselect" name="page">
<option att="1stOption" value="0">abc</option>
<option att="2ndOption" value="1" selected="">def</option>
```

I get the same results of the output before.

**"1stOption and abc"**

Now I noticed the selected="".  That doesn't look right, I've looked around in the project and I'm unable to find where that is being produced, but it is rendering properly.

I'm wondering why the selected selector isn't working properly?

Comment: Your code has errors: `att` is undefined, you are missing a space in your selector before `:selected`, and you are missing an end tag for your `<select>`.  But running your code with those errors in place or with those errors fixed does not reproduce the behavior you describe in either case.  http://jsfiddle.net/tg9QF/  Works for me.  Please post code that actually reproduces your bug - post a jsFiddle.

Comment: I originally transposed my code incorrectly and I have since editted it.  Also, I stated that it was a snippet of code so that is why I didn't include the end tag for the select.  This code is built dynamically via a COM object so I'm not sure even if I could do a fiddle that it would work correctly.  I am going to have to do more research into alternatives.

Comment: View source, copy/paste, trim irrelevent code, paste in jsFiddle.  The trim irrelevant code step is the tedious one, but in my experience, I usually find my solution through that process anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works for me -

```
var attribute = $('#Obj_cboscreen :selected').attr("att");
var name = $('#Obj_cboscreen :selected').html();

alert(attribute + name);
```

There are a couple of changes from your code.

`attr(att)` to `attr("att")`

`$('#Obj_cboscreen:selected')` to `$('#Obj_cboscreen :selected')`

The following jsfiddle shows the code working when the 'selected' attribute is added to the second option.

http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/bjWt3/

Comment: hmm...  I must of transposed the code you changed incorrectly in the question as I have the correct spaces and quotes...  Unfortunately, I'm unable to get this working.  Still don't understand why.

Comment: it's strange as the code seems to work in the jsfiddle. If you replace 'selected=""' with just 'selected' does that make a difference?

Comment: @pr101 - I think that selected="" is produced in the component...  I'm going to have to do more research...

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with att, i think this should be enclosed in quotes,
Like

```
var attribute = $('#Obj_cboscreen option:selected').attr("att");
```

True is missing in selected, always format your html, because some times its behave uncommonly

```
<select id="Obj_cboscreen" class="menubarselect" name="page">
<option att="1stOption" value="0">abc</option>
 <option att="2ndOption" value="1" selected="true">def</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here take a look at this -- maybe it will help you out:

http://jsfiddle.net/dKyrM/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var attribute = $('#Obj_cboscreen option[selected=true]').attr("att");
alert(attribute);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="Obj_cboscreen" class="menubarselect" name="page">
<option att="1stOption" value="0">abc</option>
<option att="2ndOption" value="1" selected="true">def</option>
```